# Query full Informix database version using sql query

Tags: sql, version, informix

What is the query required to get the full database version in an Informix database?

Answer (score 15):

This is the simplest query that I could find.

```
SELECT DBINFO('version','full')
FROM systables
WHERE tabid = 1;
```

The result will be something like this:

```
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC5GE
```

Comment: As documented in the Informix Knowledge Center under [DBINFO — using the version option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1491.htm#ids_sqs_1491) there are also other arguments that can be supplied in place of `'full'` to get different results.

Comment: I needed to qualify with schema name: SELECT DBINFO('version','full')
FROM informix.systables
WHERE tabid = 1